# How to record purged files into a log file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following code in a batch file to purge any files older than 60 days. I would like the log file to print the file names that have been purged for record keeping purposes. How can I do that?

```bash
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set logpath=C:\Temp\Archive
REM if not exist %logpath% md %logpath%

set FILEAGE=60
set archlog=%logpath%\Accurate_ARCHIVE.txt
set inputdir=C:\Temp

REM Set the date
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date/t') do (set DD=%%a) & (set MM=%%b) & (set YYYY=%%c)
REM * Purge files older than %FILEAGE% days from disk.

forfiles /p "%inputdir%" /s /m *.* /d -%FILEAGE% /c "cmd /c del @path" 

ECHO Folder %inputdir% was processed on %DD%-%MM%-%YYYY% >> %archlog%
ECHO Files older than %FILEAGE% days have been purged. >> %archlog%

exit %errorlevel%
```

I am expecting the log file to print the names of the files purged.

Comment: You should put `"cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path && >>0x22%archlog%0x22 echo @path"` behind the `/c` option of `forfiles`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **echo @path** to the **del @path** command.
Something like below (untested).

```
"cmd /c (del @path) & (>> %archlog% echo @path)"
```

A more advanced version incorporating comments by Aschipf and Compo.
The 0x22 puts doupble quots around the filename and prevents problems with space and other special characters in the filename.
Deleted files are reported and files that could not be deleted are reported prefixed with NOT DELETED:.

```
"cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE (del @path) & (>> 0x22%archlog%0x22 if exist @path (echo NOT DELETED: @path) else (echo @path))"
```

Comment: This idea would only write to a file those files for which deletion was attempted, not those for which deletion was successful.